# shgo - constraintsometimes work, sometimes not

Tags: optimization, constraints

Im working on optimization with constraints in scpo. In some cases it works fine, in other the results get weird. An example below:

```
from shgo import shgo
import numpy as np
def objective(x):  # (cattle-feed)
    return 10*x[0] + 23*x[1]

def cons1(x):
    return x[0] + x[1] - 100

constraints = (
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': cons1},
)
bounds = [(1, float("inf"))]*2
res = shgo(objective, bounds, iters=10, n=40, constraints=constraints)
print(res)
```

the output is the following - this one is ok

```
 message: Optimization terminated successfully.
 success: True
     fun: 1013.0000000000005
    funl: [ 1.013e+03]
       x: [ 9.900e+01  1.000e+00]
      xl: [[ 9.900e+01  1.000e+00]]
     nit: 10
    nfev: 59
   nlfev: 19
   nljev: 6
   nlhev: 0
```

however when I add one more constraint `cons2` (quite simple, if cons1 is fulfilled, then cons2 will automatically be fulfilled, but the issue also exists with more complex constraints)  - so the code is as follows:

```
from shgo import shgo
import numpy as np
def objective(x):  # (cattle-feed)
    return 10*x[0] + 23*x[1]

def cons1(x):
    return x[0] + x[1] - 100

def cons2(x):
    # return x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 3 - 200
    return x[0] + x[1] - 80

constraints = [
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': cons1},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': cons2},
]
bounds = [(1, float("inf"))]*2
res = shgo(objective, bounds, iters=10, n=40, constraints=constraints)
print(res)
```

```
message: Optimization terminated successfully.
 success: True
     fun: 6.25e+49
    funl: [ 6.250e+49  1.250e+50  2.500e+50]
       x: [ 6.250e+48  1.000e+00]
      xl: [[ 6.250e+48  1.000e+00]
           [ 1.250e+49  1.000e+00]
           [ 2.500e+49  1.000e+00]]
     nit: 10
    nfev: 208
   nlfev: 9
   nljev: 3
   nlhev: 0
```

which is completely weird - neither the function is minimized, nor constraints work properly.

Is this a bug in scpo library or am I doing something wrong?